# Monotonic log det function?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, analysis

I want to claim that the follwoing function is monotonically increasing in $d_j$.

$$\log\det\left\{\mathbf{I}+\frac{1}{d_{j}^{-\alpha}\mathbf{H}_{j}\mathbf{v}_{j}\mathbf{v}_{j}^{H}\mathbf{H}_{j}^{H}+\sigma^{2}\mathbf{I}}\right\}$$

where  $\mathbf{H_j}$ is a complex valued constant matrix. Then  $\mathbf{v_j}$ is complex valued constant vector. $\alpha$ is a real positive constant and $d_j$ is non negative real valued scalar variable, $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix. The superscript $^H$ is the conjugate transpose (Hermitian). The $\sigma^2>0$ and is a real scalar.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What is $\sigma$?

Comment: Try taking this to Math.stackexchange.com Also you can radically simplify the expression you're asking about, so why not do that *before* posting?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Could you please explain how I can simplify it? My knowledge of matrices is very limited, most I know is taking inverse of a 3 by 3 Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't write the subscipt $j$. Let $u=H_jv_j$. I assume that $\sigma>0$ and that your $1/Z$ denotes $Z^{-1}$ !!(MLT, your presentation is dismal). Let $f(d)=\log(\det(I+(d^{-\alpha}uu^*+\sigma^2I)^{-1}))$. The eigenvalues of $uu^*$ are $0$ ($n-1$ times) and $u^*u=||u||^2$. Then the eigenvalues of $I+(d^{-\alpha}uu^*+\sigma^2I)^{-1}$ are $1+1/\sigma^2$ $(n-1$ times) and $1+1/(d^{-\alpha}||u||^2+\sigma^2)$. Finally $f(d)=K+\log( 1+1/(d^{-\alpha}||u||^2+\sigma^2))$ where $K$ is a constant scalar. Clearly, it is an increasing function.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain how you got the eigenvalues please?

Comment: The rank of $uu^*$ is $1$ and its last eigenvalue is $Trace(uu^*)=Trace(u^*u)$.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate much. I have a similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489386/monotonicity-of-log-det-rd-i-d-j could you please tell me how to hand that too, if asking so is appropriate.