# Monotonicity of $\log \det R(d_i, d_j)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, matrices, analysis, functional-analysis

$R(d_i, d_j)=\log\det(\mathbf{I}+(d_{i}^{-\alpha}\mathbf{H}_{i}\mathbf{v}_{i}\mathbf{v}_{i}^{*}\mathbf{H}_{i}^{*})(d_{j}^{-\alpha}\mathbf{H}_{j}\mathbf{v}_{j}\mathbf{v}_{j}^{*}\mathbf{H}_{j}^{*}+\sigma^{2}\mathbf{I})^{-1}).$

I want to claim that this is decreasing in $d_{i}$ and  increasing in $d_{j}$. I think it is monotonic in these variables.

I tried with simulations and it works. I also can prove this for scalar case but I would like  to prove it for more general case where $\mathbf{H_i}$, $\mathbf{H_j}$ are complex valued constant matrices. Then $\mathbf{v_i}$, $\mathbf{v_j}$ are complex valued constant column vectors. $\alpha$ is a real positive constant and $d_i$, $d_j$ are non negative real valued scalar variables, $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix. The $()^*$ is the Hermitian (conjugate transpose)

Both $\mathbf{v_i}$,$\mathbf{v_j}$ exclude the all zero vector. Similarly both  $\mathbf{H_i}$, $\mathbf{H_j}$ exclude all zero matrix. And $\sigma^2>0$ a real constant. May be it may require other assumptions on these vectors and matrices, but I don't know what those may be and any suggestion is most appreciated.

I already tried it for scalar case and it holds. $$\log\left\{1+\frac{\frac{a}{x}}{\frac{b}{y}+\sigma^{2}}\right\}$$ for $a,$ $b$ positive real scalars.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how do you define $\frac{A}{B}$ for matrices $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @VedranŠego  I take it as the usual inverse, i.e., $B^{-1}$. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that $AB^{-1}$ is generally not the same as $B^{-1}A$. Do these commute in your case?

Comment: @VedranŠego It is $AB^{-1}$

Comment: @VedranŠego good to have it fixed, but in any case it didn't matter since $\det(I+AB)=\det(I+BA)$. :)

Comment: @VedranŠego so does that mean also $\det(AB)=det(BA)$ too? And does my claim above about monotonicity holds too? Thank you

Comment: @FedericoPoloni You're right, it didn't matter here, but it was so wrong I had to complain. O:-)

Comment: @MLT Yes, for square matrices: $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B) = \det(B)\det(A) = \det(BA)$. However, you have additional ${\rm I}$ added.

Comment: @MLT How did you conclude that? We were just commenting on why is it (not) wrong to write $\frac{A}{B}$ for matrices. Unless I've made a mistake in my answer, your statement holds at least for $d_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result follows from some properties of the positive semidefinite (Loewner) ordering ($X\geq Y$ and $X>Y$ mean that $X-Y$ are positive semidefinite and positive definite, respectively).

Let $A=H_iv_iv_i^*H_i^*$, $B=H_jv_j v_j^*H_j^*$, C=$\sigma^2 I$, $x=d_i^{-\alpha}$, $y=d_j^{\alpha}$. We shall only need that $A\geq 0$, $B\geq 0$, $C>0$ in the following.

The function simplifies to $\log\det(I+ xA(yB+C)^{-1})$. As argued by Vedran, we may get rid of the log. The required determinant is equal to that of $I+x(yB+C)^{-1/2}A(yB+C)^{-1/2}$ (using the identity $\det(I+XY)=\det(I+YX)$).

If $0<x_1<x_2$, $0 \leq x_1 (yB+C)^{-1/2}A(yB+C)^{-1/2} \leq x_2 (yB+C)^{-1/2}A(yB+C)^{-1/2}$, hence all eigenvalues of the LHS are smaller than those of the RHS and the required determinant is smaller.

We may also replace that determinant with the one of $I+A^{1/2}(yB+C)^{-1}A^{1/2}$.

If $0<y_1<y_2$ then $0<y_1B+C<y_2B+C$ and $0<(y_2B+C)^{-1}<(y_1B+C)^{-1}$, hence also $0<A^{1/2}(y_2B+C)^{-1}A^{1/2}<A^{1/2}(y_1B+C)^{-1}A^{1/2}$ and we conclude as above.

Comment: Could you please also explain if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are positive semidefinite?

Comment: And also could you please explain where is the positive semidefiniteness used in the proof ?

Comment: Why $A$ is SPD: write it in a basis that starts with $H_i v_i$. $B$: same reason. $C$: should be obvious. I want to use this property: if $0 \leq X \leq Y$ then $\det X \leq \det Y$. There we need SPDness of $X$ (and $Y$).  PDness of $C$ is needed because I need to invert it.  In the proof I use several properties of the Loewner ordering (I suggest you to check out a book on that if you don't know it, this is a standard application of these results).

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any suggestion for a book to check these out please?

Comment: I will use this fact in a paper. How do you wish I acknowledge you?

Comment: Horn and Johnson's *Matrix analysis* should be a good reference (Chapter 7.7 in my edition). As for acknowledging, thanks for doing it, nice of you! No special request on how to, do as you find most suitable.

Comment: Thank you. I will acknowledge you as Federico Giovanni of Institute
of Computer Science, University of Pisa, Italy. Once I finish the paper (in two weeks) I will send you a copy by email you mention on your website.

Comment: Does this also hold for $y_1=0$? I have another question which I think will be solved if so http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492697/possible-determinant-inequality-det-leftiaaib-right-1-leq-det-l. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I think it still holds for $y_1=0$, and that solves your other question. Federico Poloni is better - Giovanni is just a middle name. But maybe that doesn't deserve a citation, that's not so noteworthy, they are all standard techniques for people in matrix analysis. :)

Comment: When you say "...hence all eigenvalues of the LHS..." do you mean they are pairwise smaller? I mean taking pairs of values from LHS and RHS. I don't think all of LHS are smaller than all of RHS.

Comment: Hmm, no, actually I said that sentence out of intuition but that is indeed wrong. The correct missing step should be the following: if $0<M\leq N$, then we prove that $\det M\leq \det N$: multiplying each side by $M^{-1/2}$ on both sides we get $I \leq M^{-1/2}NM^{-1/2}$, so $x^Tx\leq x^TM^{-1/2}NM^{-1/2}x$ for each $x$, hence $M^{-1/2}NM^{-1/2}$ has all eigenvalues greater or equal than $1$, so $\det M^{-1/2}NM^{-1/2} \geq 1$, so $\det M \leq \det N$. I think you can also find this lemma direcyly on Horn-Johnson. Sorry for the mistake!

Comment: Thank you. If $0<aA<bA$ where $a,b real positive$ and $A$ is complex valued positive semidefinite matrix, isn't the pairwise eigenvalues of $aA$ smaller than $bA$? I mean first eigenvalue of $aA$ is smaller than first eigenvalue of $bA$ ? since positive semidefinite eigenvalues are positive real even if $A$ is complex right?

Comment: I just read Horn, he proves that if $A>B$ then pair wise eigenvalue inequality hold. Could you please verify I read it right? Corollary 7.7.4

Comment: It seems you are right! I didn't remember this lemma when I wrote my previous comment... So the solution in my answer does indeed work without modification in the end.

Comment: I have one question more. you take $0 \leq x_1 (yB+C)^{-1/2}A(yB+C)^{-1/2} \leq x_2 (yB+C)^{-1/2}A(yB+C)^{-1/2}$. But for the $\det$ inequality to hold it should be $0<$ i.e. two matrices are PD according the to book,  7.7.4. So is $x_1 (yB+C)^{-1/2}A(yB+C)^{-1/2}$ PD. I know for sure it is PSD but not sure if PD.

Comment: May be you take $M = I+x_1 (yB+C)^{-1/2}A(yB+C)^{-1/2}$ and $N=I+x_2 (yB+C)^{-1/2}A(yB+C)^{-1/2}$. Then I think $M, N$ are PD. But we have only proved that $x_1 (yB+C)^{-1/2}A(yB+C)^{-1/2} \leq x_2 (yB+C)^{-1/2}A(yB+C)^{-1/2}$, with out $I$, but I think addition of $I$ do not change the matrix inequality. So $M\leq N$

Comment: Well, if one of the two matrices is only PSD then the determinant is zero and the inequality should hold trivially.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, $\log$ is of no interest here, as it is a monotonous function. So, we observe

$$f(d_i, d_j) = \det \left( {\rm I} + (d_{i}^{-\alpha} H_i v_i v_i^* H_i^*)(d_j^{-\alpha} H_j v_j v_j^* H_j^* + \sigma^2 {\rm I})^{-1} \right).$$

Since $H_i$, $H_j$, $v_i$, and $v_j$ are constant matrices/vectors, we can simplify this a bit by introducing $u_i := H_i v_i$ and $u_j := H_j v_j$:

$$f(d_i, d_j) = \det \left( {\rm I} + (d_{i}^{-\alpha} u_i u_i^*)(d_j^{-\alpha} u_j u_j^* + \sigma^2 {\rm I})^{-1} \right).$$

Using [Sylvester's determinant theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem) or, more precisely, its consequence (taken from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Sylvester.27s_determinant_theorem))

$$\det(X + AB) = \det(X) \det( I_n + BX^{-1}A ),$$

for $A = {\rm I}$, $B = d_{i}^{-\alpha} u_i u_i^*$, and $X = d_j^{-\alpha} u_j u_j^* + \sigma^2 {\rm I}$, we see that

\begin{align*}
f(d_i, d_j) &= \det \left( {\rm I} + (d_{i}^{-\alpha} u_i u_i^*)(d_j^{-\alpha} u_j u_j^* + \sigma^2 {\rm I})^{-1} \right) \\
&= \frac{\det \left( (d_j^{-\alpha} u_j u_j^* + \sigma^2 {\rm I}) + (d_{i}^{-\alpha} u_i u_i^*) \right)}{\det (d_j^{-\alpha} u_j u_j^* + \sigma^2 {\rm I})}.
\end{align*}

Using the fact that $u_i u_i^*$ is positive semidefinite, and that $d_i^{-\alpha}$ decreases when $d_i$ increases, it should be fairly easy to show that the numerator also decreases when $d_i$ increases.

Right now I don't have a good idea for $d_j$, so I'll just leave this half answered. However, it does seem like the statement holds.