# Eigenvalues of $(A+B)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, matrices, analysis

Suppose I know the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$. Is there a way to write eigenvalues of the following?

(1). $(A+B)$

(2). $(I+A)$

(3). $(I+A)^{-1}$

(4). $(A+B)^{-1}$

where $A, B$ are matrices in complex field and $I$ is identity matrix. Also in the cases (3) and (4) is there a way to write the inverses matrices also?

PS. This is related to my previous question and is not homework [Monotonic log det function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489370/monotonic-log-det-function)

Appreciate any form of insight. Thank you.

Edit I also want to write the eigenvalues of $AB^{-1}$ from $A$ and $B$. Is it possible under some assumptions? The matrices are defined in the complex field. I need this to answer another question [Monotonicity of $\log \det R(d_i, d_j)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489386/monotonicity-of-log-det-rd-i-d-j)

Comment: (1). (A+B): No
(2). (I+A): each eigenvalue increases by 1
(3). (I+A)−1: $1/(\lambda_i + 1)$
(4). (A+B)−1: No

Comment: @Memming Thank you and much appreciate. Please see if the answer below is compatible with your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general (diagonalisable) matrices $A,B$, their sets of eigenvalues do not determine those of $A+B$; since their eigenvectors are unrelated there is really nothing easy one can say here. If $A$ and $B$ commute, then one can say a bit more: the matrices have a basis of common eigenvectors, and the eigenvalues of $A+B$ can be found by matching up the eigenvalues of $A$ with those of $B$ in some manner, and adding up those pairs. Note that there will in genral be $n!$ different matchings, so still potentially that many different outcomes (using diagonal matrices, it is easy to see such possibilties can indeed be realised).

On the other hand eigenvectors of $A$ are also eigenvectors of $A+\mu I$ for any scalar $\mu$, and assuming invertibility also eigenvectors of $A^{-1}$; you can easily see what happens to the eigenvalues. This gives positive answers to (2) and (3).

Comment: Thank you. I included an edit to the question. Could you please explain that too. I need that to understand another question of mine http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489386/monotonicity-of-log-det-rd-i-d-j.

Answer (score 1):

If matrices $A, A^*, B, B^*$ commute, they are simultaneously diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$. Then you can simply assume (by a possible change of basis) that you are working with diagonal matrices. In general, there are more subtetlies like MvL points out.

Comment: Thank you. I also want to write the eigenvalues of $AB^{-1}$ from $A$ and $B$. Is it possible under some assumptions? I need it for another question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489386/monotonicity-of-log-det-rd-i-d-j which is related.